# django is not using my custom translation

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, localization, internationalization

I have a django project with django rest framwork. I want a multi language project and I am trying to have my custom translation. I use drf document https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/internationalization/#adding-new-translations and also django document and other sources but know django is still using drf default translation. my overriding is not applied and new strings are no translated.
eg I override this line in .po file

```
msgid "Username"
msgstr ""
```

to

```
msgid "Username"
msgstr "یوزنیم"
```

but it is translated to "نام کاربری"
and  I add this line

```
msgid "there is a user with this national id"
msgstr "سامتینگ"
```

and use that message as a serializer unique validator error but it is not translated

```
national_id = serializers.CharField(validators=[validate_national_id, UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message='there is a user with this national id') ], allow_blank=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should mark the string as a translation string:

```
from django.utils.translation import gettext as _

national_id = serializers.CharField(validators=[validate_national_id, UniqueValidator(queryset=User.objects.all(), message=_('there is a user with this national id')) ], allow_blank=True)
```

read the usage of translation https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/i18n/translation/